# Are SFP compatible with mini-GBIC

Tags: synology

I am shopping around to get a Synology NAS. Particularly the Synology DS2015XS which has 2 SFP+ 10GB port. I currently own a Cisco SG200-26 with 2 mini-GBIC. I have no idea how SFP+ or mini-GBIC work, so can someone tell me if these two are compatible? Is the mini-GBIC faster than the regular gigabite port thats on the SG200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10Gb SPF+ sockets normally backward compatible with SFP Rev.C, but you should double check with Synology.

The CISCO SG200-26?? should be mini-GBIC / SFP, that means it can only support 10/100/1000 Mbps with copper (100m), multi-mode fiber (up to 2km), and single-mode fiber (over 10km) connection.

The remaining choice was using 100 / 1000 Mbps SX / LX / LHX / ZX or BX, buy the SFP that is compatible with the equipment that talks with the same physical type, fiber type, number of fiber(s), wavelength, to setup the communication channel.

In my experience using the copper port and a copper based mini-GBIC performs the same. SFP normally used with fiber for long distance communication or the communication path need to passes through high EM signal areas (with high EM noise).

Comment: Thank you. So that means the 10Gbp from the Synology isn't really going to improve anything since the bottle neck is on my Cisco SG200 because the mini-GBIC is only 1Gbps. I would not gain anything (throughput) beside longer distance from using the mini-GBIC?

Comment: In terms of bandwidth, no you didn't have improvement. Furthermore, unlink running on copper port if you use SFP on one side and SFP+ on the other side, they may not really talk with each other.